# Using MSAL for Angular and NGXLogger

Tags: msal-angular, ngx-logger

I recently upgraded my Angular application to use MSAL for Angular V2.X.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular

My app uses NGXLogger for logging.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-logger

I am getting these errors when I run my app:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! NGXLogger
```

and

```
ERROR Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ErrorHandler
```

NOTE: Update: MSAL for Angular is NOT using NGXLogger!!
It looks like MSAL for Angular now uses NGXLogger.

I am seeking guidance on how to fix the issue so MSAL for Angular and my app can use NGXLogger.

Answer (score 0):

MSAL for Angular does not use NGXLogger.

The way I fixed the error was to remove the provider specified in the module and instead use `provideIn: root` for my ErrorHandler and my LoggerService (that uses NGXLogger)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
```

and

```
import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoggerService {
```